# How to extract hour from a dataset in a 24h format

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract the `hour` from the column date in a `24-h` format.
It doesn't seem to work as I am only getting the `AM`, from the following dataset:
[Chicago crime](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=bigquery-public-data&d=chicago_crime&page=dataset&project=data-analyst-home-assignment&ws=!1m5!1m4!4m3!1sbigquery-public-data!2schicago_crime!3scrime)

```
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
# Convert timestamp to AM/PM format
df["timestamp"] = df["timestamp"].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p"))
df['hour'] = df['timestamp'].dt.hour
```

The `hour` part is from 1-12, however, I don’t seem to have the `AM/PM`, but  only the `UTC` in the time stamp.
Data in the time stamp column - date, is shown below;

```
date
-----------------------
2019-08-29 06:40:00 UTC
2010-03-07 01:21:00 UTC
2002-10-22 11:09:33 UTC
2012-02-20 09:00:00 UTC
2022-10-04 07:24:00 UTC
2005-09-28 04:00:00 UTC
2001-11-21 02:01:03 UTC
2021-01-24 01:00:00 UTC
2005-12-10 08:00:00 UTC
2011-10-18 04:00:00 UTC
2008-02-06 01:00:00 UTC
2001-07-30 03:36:18 UTC
2015-10-11 05:00:00 UTC
2010-02-04 10:15:00 UTC
2003-08-01 04:38:49 UTC
```

Comment: Please include a sample of the data in the question. For more info, see [mre] and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: Hey I added a link for the whole data set for reference, the column I’m interested in is column date

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, it needs to be as text, [not a picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

Using the following version you can extract the hour from the sample without the need to convert the datatype of entire column.

```
from datetime import datetime
sample = "2019-08-29 06:40:00 UTC"
parsed_sample = datetime.strptime(sample, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
hour = parsed_sample.hour
```

Here %Z represents the time zone.

Comment: still getting only 1-12

Comment: for example, this is what i get in column I applied the DateTime.strptime to 2005-02-06 10:19:00+00:00

Comment: df['datetime_time'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"))